# Summation of array variable in gekko

Tags: python, arrays, gekko

*I tried this code but it seems that something is wrong. Normaly print (z.value) must return a single number but in my case it returns an array. could someone help please*

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xm = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
ym = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.8,2.0])
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Param(value=xm)
a = m.FV()
a.STATUS=1
y = m.CV(value=ym)
y.FSTATUS=1

z = None

m.Equation(y==0.1*m.exp(a*x))

z = m.Intermediate(sum([y[i] for i in range(len(y))]))


m.options.IMODE = 2

m.solve(disp=False)

print(z.value)

print(y.value)
```

Comment: You created the Gekko variables and parameters, 'x', 'y', as arrays in these lines, `x = m.Param(value=xm)`, `y = m.CV(value=ym)`. So, `z` also ended up having the same size array as the others. 'z' might have a single value in the size of the array.

Comment: Because `z` is not engaged in the optimization calculation as a variable or parameter, it may keep summing up the initial values of 'y'. You may want to sum the result of 'y' using `np.sum` after the `m.solve()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `z=m.vsum(y)` to create a summation of the variable across the data sets with `IMODE=2`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xm = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
ym = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.8,2.0])
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Param(value=xm)
a = m.FV()
a.STATUS=1
y = m.CV(value=ym)
y.FSTATUS=1
m.Equation(y==0.1*m.exp(a*x))

z = m.vsum(y)

m.options.IMODE = 2
m.solve(disp=False)
print(z.value)
print(y.value)
```

Your method to define `z` creates a summation of the initial values `ym`. When defining a model in Gekko, it is important to realize that the model is defined once for each data set. Gekko then takes the model and solves it for each data set. This is also the same approach when solving over multiple time points. Even though multiple values are reported for `z`, there is only one unique value (`4.3146`).